# Instance members can't be accessed from a static method Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, timer, static

Im trying to call `playRefreshBar` in my code , but i get warning like this

> Instance members can't be accessed from a static method

this is code in my static

```
  static List<charts.Series<Spending, String>> createRandomData(){
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds:1000),(){
      playRefreshBar();
    });
  }
```

code playRefreshBar

```
  void playRefreshBar() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: refreshTime), (Timer t){
      final random = new Random();

      final data = [
        new Spending('2013', random.nextInt(1000000)),
        new Spending('2014', random.nextInt(1000000)),
        new Spending('2015', random.nextInt(1000000)),
        new Spending('2016', random.nextInt(1000000)),
        new Spending('2017', random.nextInt(1000000)),
        new Spending('2018', random.nextInt(1000000)),
        new Spending('2019', random.nextInt(1000000)),
      ];

      return[
        new charts.Series(id: 'Spending',
            data: data,
            domainFn: (Spending sp, _) => sp.year,
            measureFn: (Spending sp , _) => sp.spending,
            labelAccessorFn: (Spending sp, _) => '${sp.year}: \$${sp.spending}'
        )
      ];
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 12):

The reason a static method cannot call an instance method is because the instance that you want to use is not included.

Since you can create any number of instance objects that the instance method will be used on, the static (single global method) needs to know which one you are referring to.

```
static List<charts.Series<Spending, String>> createRandomData(){
 Timer(Duration(milliseconds:1000),(){
   instance.playRefreshBar();
 });
}
```

where instance is

```
final instance = new ClassThatHasPlayRefreshBar();
```

Or, you will need to make the instance method also static

```
static void playRefreshBar()
```