# Problem with displaying notifications in static app bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to display notification count in app bar, so in stateless class MainAppBar I fetch notifications count like this

```
class MainAppBar {
  AuthService? _authService;
  ObavijestiService? _obavijestiService;
  Client _client = Client();
  List<Notifikacija2> _notifikacije = [];

 MainAppBar() {
    _authService = AuthService(_client.init());
    _obavijestiService = ObavijestiService(_client.init());
    int num = getObavijesti() as int;
  }

  Future<int> getObavijesti() async {
    var user = await _authService!.getCurrentUser();
    var data = await _obavijestiService!.getNotifications(user!.userId);

    _notifikacije = data;
    int broj = _notifikacije.length;

    return broj;
  }
```

But i get error when trying to display notification count:
"Instance members can't be accessed from a static method.
Try removing the reference to the instance member, or removing the keyword 'static' from the method."

```
  static AppBar buildAppBar(String title, String subtitle, BuildContext context,
      {String tab1 = "ab", String tab2 = "av", /*int notificationNum = 0*/}) {
...
Center(
            child: Badge(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.5),
                badgeContent: Text(getObavijesti().toString()),//error on this line
//Instance members can't be accessed from a static method. Try removing the reference to the instance member, or removing the keyword 'static' from the method."
                badgeColor: Colors.blue,
                position: BadgePosition.topEnd(top: 1, end: 3),
                animationType: BadgeAnimationType.fade,
                showBadge: num > 0 ? true : false,//The operator '>' isn't defined for the type 'Type'
                child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      Navigator.of(context)
                          .pushReplacementNamed('/notifications');
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications))),
          ),
... }
```

How could I get the data in this static AppBar

Comment: where you define  this `_notifikacije ` ? avoid using `final` or `const`  if its not static value

Comment: I edited question  so you can see

Comment: does this solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/57217044/12838877 ?

Comment: yes I solved it was a stupid mistake, I just needed to add ```badgeContent: Text(mainAppBar.getObavijesti().toString()),```

Comment: but it returns Instance of 'Future<int>' I need to convert it to int

Comment: since it `Future` you have yo add `await`